# Google Sheets Api - add-on read from another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

Problem description:

I want to create an add-on on my google sheet (g-1). When the user opens the add-on, I want to immediately read another google spreadsheet (g-2) and populate dropdowns on g-1 based on those columns.

I have enabled the Googlesheet Api
in Code.js:

```
function readSpreadsheet() {
  var questions = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("_ID_", "SHEET!A2:k").values
  if (!questions) {
    return 'No data found.';
  } else {
    return questions
  }
}
```

the function above works, because if I add that to the title on the add-on I see the correct number of columns:

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('QuestionBank').setTitle(readSpreadsheet().length)
```

or I can print the first row

```
readSpreadsheet()[0]
```

............

So far so good.

Now in my html file, QuestionBank.html,

Problem #1. I am not able to call `readSpreadsheet`, it returns undefined. var question_rows returns undefined.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

  /**
    read all rows, upon clicking on sync button. But this is not necessary if I can populate the dropdowns on load
  **/


  $(function() {
    $('#sync').click(readSpreadsheet);
  });

  function readSpreadsheet() {
    this.disabled = true;
    $('#error').remove();
    var question_rows = google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(
          function(textAndTranslation, element) {
            element.disabled = false;
          })
        .withFailureHandler(
          function(msg, element) {
            element.disabled = false;
          })
        .withUserObject(this)
        .readSpreadsheet();

        for (var row = 0; row < question_rows.length; row++) {
          alert(question_rows[row])
        }
  }
</script>
```

Problem #2: I have several dropdowns that I want their value to be unique value of the g-2 columns. I want those dropdowns to be populated when the add-on opens.

```
<select class="filter">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

so instead of Volvo, etc, I want the first column of my data, unique values

Problem #3: if on load is not possible, I can include a button to read the data and populate the dropdowns

```
<button class="sync-button" id="sync">sync</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following answers?

#### Answer for Problem #1

[google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) doesn't return values. When it uses values from google.script.run, in your case, `textAndTranslation` of `withSuccessHandler` is the returned value. So you can modify `readSpreadsheet()` as follows.

```
function readSpreadsheet() {
  this.disabled = true;
  $('#error').remove();
  google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(withSuccessHandler)
      .withFailureHandler(
        function(msg, element) {
          element.disabled = false;
        })
      .withUserObject(this)
      .readSpreadsheet();
}

function withSuccessHandler(textAndTranslation, element) {
  element.disabled = false;
  var question_rows = textAndTranslation;
  for (var row = 0; row < question_rows.length; row++) {
    alert(question_rows[row])
  }
}
```

#### Answer for Problem #2

You can achieve it by putting google.script.run in `$(function() {})`. The sample is as follows. This is a sample. So please modify the variables to yours.

```
<select class="filter"></select>
<script>
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(sample).readSpreadsheet();
});

function sample(data) {
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.filter').append($('<option>').html(data[i]).val(data[i]));
  }
}
```

#### Answer for Problem #3

Of course, you can set values to `<select class="filter"></select>` using a button.

If I misunderstand your questions, I'm sorry.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!! I combined it with lodash library and it worked like a champ!

Comment: @Sarah A Welcome. Thank you, too.